# How to print MongoDB databases in Python

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a MongoDB database that is storing data from ROS topics that my robot is logging. I am trying to print the data in MongoDB by using the following python script:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('cpr-j100-0101', 62345)
db1 = client.front_scan
db2 = client.cmd_vel
db3 = client.odometry_filtered
print db1
print db2
print db3
```

but I dont get the result I want when I run this script. I have attached the result of running this script as an image. Instead of this, I would like to actually be able to access the data within mongoDB.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCZIc.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can't print a database before accessing it. First, you need to select what database you need to print. For an example let's think you have 2 collections in db1 as coll1 and coll2. By printing the database means you are going to print the documents of the collections that are in the database.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
db = client.myDatabase
#my dummy database is myDatabase.
coll1 = db.coll1 #selecting the coll1 in myDatabase
for document in coll1.find():
    print (document)
```

so from the above code, you can print all the documents in the coll1 collection of myDatabase. The same manner you can print the databases one by one.

Answer (score 0):

With this script you actually don't do much. You just create three databases and that's basically it. You never insert data, or read data from the database. You're just printing the database object. 
I believe, that [MongoDB Manual](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html) should be useful...